# Having ffmpeg add a repeating text overlay on a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm looking to create an overlay that cycles through the characters in a string over and over. I've succeeded in using a sendcmd file to put A, B, C, D, E on the first 5 seconds of a video

```
0  drawtext reinit 'text=A';
1  drawtext reinit 'text=B';
2  drawtext reinit 'text=C';
3  drawtext reinit 'text=D';
4  drawtext reinit 'text=E';
```

But it doesn't cycle and I haven't been able to find a way to make it, because sendcmd looks like it just takes a simple timecode. I could make a command file 3600 lines long for my hour video, with those commands in over and over (the command file would be generated programmatically so not onerous)

---

After some considerable experimenting I was able to do it with 5 separate drawtext:

```
drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/bauhs93.ttf:fontsize=1024:fontcolor=white@0.1:bordercolor=black@0.1:borderw=10:r=250:text='A':x=if(trunc(mod(t\,5))\,-2000\,(w-tw)/2),
drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/bauhs93.ttf:fontsize=1024:fontcolor=white@0.1:bordercolor=black@0.1:borderw=10:r=250:text='B':x=if(trunc(mod(t\,5))-1\,-2000\,(w-tw)/2),
drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/bauhs93.ttf:fontsize=1024:fontcolor=white@0.1:bordercolor=black@0.1:borderw=10:r=250:text='C':x=if(trunc(mod(t\,5))-2\,-2000\,(w-tw)/2),
drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/bauhs93.ttf:fontsize=1024:fontcolor=white@0.1:bordercolor=black@0.1:borderw=10:r=250:text='D':x=if(trunc(mod(t\,5))-3\,-2000\,(w-tw)/2),
drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/bauhs93.ttf:fontsize=1024:fontcolor=white@0.1:bordercolor=black@0.1:borderw=10:r=250:text='E':x=if(trunc(mod(t\,5))-4\,-2000\,(w-tw)/2)
```

But as can be seen, I have to repeat a lot of stuff here. Is there any slicker way? It does seem to have a noticeable effect on encoding speed the more chars are added

I was hoping that text expressions would help but it seems I can only return numerics from the values, so this expression didn't work out:

```
%{e:if(trunc(mod(t,5)),'A', '')%{e:if(trunc(mod(t,5))-1,'B', '') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just created a text file containing thousands of sendcmd commands